# Boot Issues with Ubuntu Server 16.04 on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: boot

I'm running Ubuntu Server found [here](https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/download/) on a raspberry pi 3. I flashed Ubuntu onto my microsd, booted on the pi and was able to run successfully. However, everytime I poweroff and then power on again, the process stalls. Any solutions?

Edit: The process stalls when starting kernel. If I re-flash the sd card, and then boot a fresh ubuntu server, it works fine.

Comment: Please provide any error messages that you get. Could you please take a screenshot, edit your post and show it?

Answer (score 0):

The image at the "Flavour Maker" site has unattended upgrades turned on.

One of the upgrades it automatically downloads breaks the boot process on my RPi3 model B (not "+"), so it hangs at the "Starting kernel..." phase.

If you don't turn it off, **and** make sure it hasn't already downloaded upgrades, the next time you install anything with apt it will install those upgrades and hose your system.

I haven't had time to figure out exactly which upgrade package is causing the failure, because I'm now in the middle of my **FOURTH** (bleep)ing complete re-install caused by it.

After more than a decade of using Ubuntu as my main desktop OS, and several years for headless servers and SBCs, I have to say that, if this were my first experience with it, it would put me off Ubuntu forever. Between fighting with cloud-init to set my simple static networking configuration, and having my system commit suicide because I forgot to edit an obscure config file to prevent it, it's like being back in the pre-disto 1990s.